# How to handle duplicate content in a tabbed area?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

On my home page I have a tabbed section that loads the content via JavaScript. I have 5 tabs that can be clicked. For example, there's an "about us" tab that has a couple of paragraphs in it and a read more button at the bottom. The problem is, when you click on the "read more" button, you're taken to the aboutus.html page which contains those same two paragraphs that are on the home page. What's a good way to go about handling this? Or do I not even need to worry about it since it's only a couple of paragraphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you have nothing to worry about. You are simply showing an excerpt of the longer page with a direct link to the full content. The search engines will figure that out ok.

In this example the "About" content is going to be only one small part of the overall homepage content. The important thing is to make sure that is is not mistaken as the most important part of the homepage content by utilising H1s, H2s etc to structure the page.

Finally see the full guidelines from Google on Duplicate content here for further reading http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359

HTH

Comment: And he is referencing content which are being loaded via Javascript. For Google these content snippets aren't even existent. No duplicate content issues at all to worry about (except you are inline-loading the javascript content, meaning the content the javascript is referencing to is already in the html and not loaded from an external file).

Comment: Google can now read some content generated by AJAX/JS however (see @mattcutts at http://goo.gl/F9et1). Also there are some web experiments which show that simple JS generated content (for example a straighforward document.write()) does get indexed. See http://www.adherewebdesign.com/can-google-index-javascript-generated-content-results/

Comment: @DKOATED That's what I had originally thought too, but I ran my site through a couple of search engine simulators, they were picking up on all of the content.

Comment: ok, show us an example how you load the js. pretty sure google doesn't play ball if the content is external.